# Implementing "app.exe -instruction file" notation in C++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have a project for my Data Structures class, which is a file compressor that works using Binary Trees and other stuff. We are required to "zip" and "unzip" any given file by using the following instructions in the command line:

For compressing:    *compressor.exe -zip file.whatever*

For uncompressing:  *compressor.exe -unzip file.zip*

We are programming in **C++**. I use the IDE Code::Blocks and compile using GCC in Windows.

My question is: **How do you even implement that??!!** How can you make your .exe receive those parameters in command line, and then execute them the way you want?

Also, anything special to have in mind if I want that implementation to compile in Linux?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo logré, I gotz it!!

I now have a basic understanding on how to use the **argc** and **argv[ ]** parameters on the **main()** function (I *always* wondered what they were good for...). For example, if I put in the command line:

*compressor.exe -unzip file.zip*

Then:

- argc initializes in '3' (number of arguments in line)
- argv[0] == "compressor.exe" (name of app.)
- argv[1] == "-unzip"
- argv[2] == "file.zip"

Greg (not 'Creg', sorry =P) and Bemrose, thank you guys for your help!! ^^

Answer (score 9):

You may want to look in your programming text for the signature of the `main` function, your program's entry point.  That's where you'll be able to pull in those command line parameters.

I don't want to be more detailed than that because this is apparently a key point of the assignment, and if I ever find myself working with you, I'll expect you to be able to figure this sort of stuff out on your own once you've received an appropriate nudge.  :)

Good luck!

Comment: 'argc' and 'argv[]'... I suspected so! >=D

I've never worked with the main() arguments before, but... I guess there is where my answer resides. Time to do some research!

Thanks Creg! ^^

Comment: Waw - I like the way you don't want to spoil the guy's lookup-fun!

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, the Single UNIX Specification / POSIX defines [getopt](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html) in unistd.h to handle the parsing of arguments for you.  While this is a C function, it should also work in C++.

GNU GLIBC [has this](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Getopt.html) in addition to getopt_long (in getopt.h) to support GNU's extended --style .

Comment: It's not spec'd in this Q, but if you check NeoGlitch's other question you'll see that he needs platform-independent solutions.  getopt isn't ANSI C, so it won't be available on the Window's platform.

Comment: I just assumed that, since he was using GCC, he was also using something like MinGW, which has unistd.h and getopt.h.

Comment: There's also a getopt for windows: getpot. You can download this from sourceforge. Worked for me.